# How to expand and collapse three div's side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('name') == 'show') {
            $("#sidebar").animate({
                width: '10%'
            }).hide()
            $("#map").animate({
                width: '89%'
            });
            $(this).data('name', 'hide')
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").animate({
                width: '29%'
            }).show()
            $("#map").animate({
                width: '70%'
            });
            $(this).data('name', 'show')
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#map {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 19%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#toggle {
    width: 10%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-right: 6.5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">HEADER
    <input type="button" data-name="show" value="Toggle" id="toggle">
</div>
<div id="map">MAP</div>
<div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
```

I am a beginner in `angularjs`, `jquery` and `css`. I want to create three div with toggle side by side 
Please help me how to do that in angularjs.

In normal mode Example:-

[image]

It will be like this.

If I expand center div it needs to be like this Example:-

[image]

If I expand last div it needs to be like this Example:-

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: I done for 2 div but put three div I struggle

Comment: I shared the sample code with two div

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: do you want to achieve this in single button or click on the div?

Comment: Look this: http://codepen.io/vishnuprasad/pen/MbZqgW

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this. All the div can be expanded in any order. To switch back into normal position, click on the expanded div again.

Width in compressed and expanded states are expressed in percentage and you can change them in the css, according to your requirement. Also I added `transition` property for smooth functioning.

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/atulb29007/pen/rWXYbG).

```js
$("a.expansion-btn").click(function (){
  classes = this.className;
  var divNumber = classes.slice(-1);
  var toGetId = "#div-"+divNumber;
  if ($(toGetId).hasClass("expanded-div")){
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div expanded-div");
  }
  else{
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div expanded-div").addClass("compressed-div");;
   $(toGetId).removeClass("compressed-div").addClass("expanded-div");    
  }  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
.normal-div{
  width:33.33%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.expanded-div{
  width:80%;
}
.compressed-div{
  width:10%;
}
#div-1{
  background-color:green;
}
#div-2{
  background-color:red;
}
#div-3{
  background-color:blue;
}
a.expansion-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-1">
    <a class="expansion-btn exp-1">click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-2">
    <a class="expansion-btn exp-2">click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-3">
    <a class="expansion-btn exp-3">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to do reset? Back to normal position?

Comment: sorry for not thinkng of that earlier but can you wait for five minutes

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to toggle between divs then do something like this.

```js
// varible for holding div index
var i = 0,
  // cache divs
  $div = $('.div');;

// bind click event handler
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $div
  // remove both class from all elements
    .removeClass('active nonactive')
    // get element by index
    .eq(i)
    // add active class
    .addClass('active')
    // get siblings
    .siblings()
    // add nonactive class
    .addClass('nonactive');
  // update index 
  i = ++i % $div.length;
})
```

```css
.div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block
}
.active {
  width: 75%;
}
.nonactive {
  width: 10%;
}
.active,
.nonactive {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle">toggle</button>
<br>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

---

Or if you want to toggle when clicked a button inside the div then do something like this.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this)
    // get div 
    .parent()
    // remove nonactive class from clicked element
    .removeClass('nonactive')
    // toggle active class
    .toggleClass('active')
    // get sibling divs
    .siblings()
    // remove active class from siblings
    .removeClass('active')
    // toggle nonactive class based on the clicked element 
    .toggleClass('nonactive', $(this).parent().is('.active'));
})
```

```css
.div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 30%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block
}
.active {
  width: 75%;
}
.nonactive {
  width: 10%;
}
.div,
.active,
.nonactive {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="div">
    <button class="toggle">toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <button class="toggle">toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <button class="toggle">toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div id="header">HEADER
        <input type="button" data-name="show" value="Toggle" id="toggle">
    </div>
    <div id="maincont">
        <div id="map" class="active">MAP</div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="inactive">SIDEBAR</div>
        <div id="sidebar1" class="inactive">SIDEBAR1</div>
    </div>
```

script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {     
            $("#toggle").click(function () {

                        var $div = $('#maincont').find(".active");
                        $div.removeClass('active').addClass("inactive").next().addClass("active");      

                        $('#maincont').find(".inactive").animate({
                            width: '10%'
                        })

                        $('#maincont').find(".active").animate({
                            width: '79%'
                        });           

             });

    });
```

css.

```
         html, body {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        #map {  
            height: 80%;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        .active{
          width:78%;
           float: left;
           height: 100px;
        }
        .inactive{
          width:10%;
           float: left;
           border: 1px solid;
            height: 100px;
        }
        #sidebar {   
            height: 80%;
            float: left;

        }
        #toggle {
            width: 10%;
            height: 40%;
            margin-right: 6.5%;
            margin-top: 3.5%;
            float: right;
        }
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/x2xh579o/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with **angularjs**, here is a simple solution with no fancy CSS:

Suppose you have some array of objects that describe the panels/divs in the controller, e.g.

```
$scope.panels = [{
    title: "One",
    expanded: true
  }, {
    title: "Two"
  }, {
    title: "Three"
  }];
```

The `expanded` flag just track which panel is actually expanded. By default the first one.

Then when you click on a panel, this function set the flag to the selected panel:

```
  $scope.expandPanel = function(panel) {
     $scope.panels.forEach(p => p.expanded = false);
     panel.expanded = true;
  }
```

And you display all that in a `ng-repeat` loop where the key thing is to set dynamically the class depending on the `expanded` flag with `ng-class`:

```
<div class="panel" 
     ng-class="{'expanded': panel.expanded, 'reduced': !panel.expanded}" 
     ng-repeat="panel in panels" ng-click="expandPanel(panel)">
  <span>{{panel.title}}</span>
</div>
```

See it [live with this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/098RpfhB6lk3de5282sN?p=preview).

Note: `.panel`, `.expanded` and `.reduced` classes are define in the plunker css file.