# Creating 3 Div's that expand when clicked and show content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create 3 divs that are inline-block and when you click them they expand (using code from answer Pranav C Balan [How to expand and collapse three div's side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197957/how-to-expand-and-collapse-three-divs-side-by-side))

I have 3 Plus icons that rotate when selected to show an x and then if it is selected again or if a different div is selected it rotates back to a plus. The 3 main divs expand when clicked just like in the example from Pranav in the link above.

My problem is I want some content to show up when the div is selected and if it is selected again or if another div is selected then the content is hidden.

My current code shows the content and hides it if a different div is selected, but the problem comes in when the same div is hit a second time all of the content shows.

I am not very good with Jquery (hence why I am using code found in a stack overflow discussion) and I need help to make this work??

Here is a codepen of what I currently have:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orpGMj

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 
button {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  background: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
 float:right;
}

button span {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button2 span:first-of-type, button2 span:last-of-type {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

 .plus1{
  top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    width: 10%;
    left: 45%;
 }
 .plus2{
  left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 45%;
 }
 .x1{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 .x2{
  transform:rotate(-45deg)
 }
 
 .div {
   height: 300px;
   width: 30%;
   border: solid 1px black;
   display: inline-block
 }
 .active {
   width: 75%;
 }
 .nonactive {
   width: 10%;
 }
 .toggle{
  cursor:pointer;
 }

 .toggle2{
  content:"-";
  font-size:40px;
  float: right;
     padding-top:0px;
  padding-right:10px;
 }
 .div,
 .active,
 .nonactive {
   -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 } 
 .box1{
  background-color: aqua;
 }
 .box2{
  background-color: bisque;
 }
 .box3{
  background-color: darkseagreen;
 }
 .information{
  display:none;
 }
 .showinfo{
  position:absolute;
 }
</style>




<div class="container">
 <div class="div box1">
  <button class="toggle">
   <span class="plus1"></span><span class="plus2"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="content information">
   <p>This is the biggest test yet on div 1.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="div box2">
  <button class="toggle">
   <span class="plus1"></span><span class="plus2"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="content information">
   <p>This is the biggest test yet on div 2.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="div box3">
  <button class="toggle">
   <span class="plus1"></span><span class="plus2"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="content information">
   <p>This is the biggest test yet on div 3.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script>
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
  $(this)
    // get div 
    .parent()
    // remove nonactive class from clicked element
    .removeClass('nonactive')
    // toggle active class
    .toggleClass('active') 
    // get sibling divs
    .siblings()
    // remove active class from siblings
    .removeClass('active')
    // toggle nonactive class based on the clicked element 
    .toggleClass('nonactive', $(this).parent().is('.active'));
});
 
 //Toggles the Plus button to rotate -- not sure why this works??
 $('.toggle').click(function() { 
   $(this)
  //finding the children of the button
  .children()
  // remove class for non toggle
  .removeClass('x2')
  //toggle rotation for button
  .toggleClass("x1")
  // get sibling divs
  .parent().parent().siblings().children().children()
  //removing the rotation
  .removeClass('x1')
  // toggle nonactive class based on the clicked element 
  .toggleClass('', $(this).parent().is('.active'));
 });
 
 //Toggles the Information to come out. -- doesn't work correctly
$('.toggle').click(function() { 
  $(this)
    // get div 
    .next()
    // remove nonactive class from clicked element
    .removeClass('information')
    // toggle active class
    .toggleClass('showinfo') 
    // get sibling divs
    .parent().siblings().children(".content")
    // remove active class from siblings
    .removeClass('showinfo')
    // toggle nonactive class based on the clicked element 
    .toggleClass('information', $(this).parent().is('.active'));
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery triggering all `.removeClass('nonactive')` causing all content to show up

this class shouldn't be used as selector to show the content.

I fix it by adding this style

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
.content.showinfo {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's the pen
https://codepen.io/somuch72/pen/JQMObR

Comment: You should also put delay on showing up its content, when you click center, then click right, the content overlapped.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works great! Now I can work on styling it and adding a delay like somuch72 recommended.